# VB.NET/WIN32/WMI Best way to monitor opening network connections

Tags: vb.net, sockets, winapi, tcp, netstat

I'm developing my own antimalware application. I have successfully implemented file system and process monitoring and now I'm looking for "some kind of firewall feature". I have already done some research and found iphlpapi.dll, netstat -o parsing.

Exactly, I would like to **receive event** with following data, when new IP (TCP/UDP/whatever) connection is opened.

- **Remote IP address**
- Protocol (TCP/UDP/...)
- Port
- **ID of process which opened connection**

I don't want to run timer which still checks netstat output, because it's not effective. I need to suspend process (I know how to suspend process) fastly, when connection to malicious IP is detected.

Comment: Is your question "what is the best way to do monitoring" or "what is the fastest" or "easiest"? Are you just looking for a packet sniffer for opening connections? I'd suggest looking at Pcap.net if so.

Comment: I'm not going to see network traffic. The only information I would like to obtain are described in list in question above. I would like to check remote IP and if my DB consider it as malicious, it should suspend associated process and allow user to decide what action will be taken (continue, kill process, additionaly add filter via iphlpapi.dll).

Easiest way is (afaik) to parse netstat output, but it can take about 10 seconds. And in this ten seconds many private data can be send. I'm looking for good and fast way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that besides writing a driver the only way to do this is Event Tracing for Windows (ETW). Check .NET System.Diagnostics.Eventing

About ETW https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363668(v=vs.85).aspx

In the ETW you can start from the following three providers:

- Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture
- Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP
- Microsoft-Windows-Networking-Correlation